# How to decompose a 3x3 transformation matrix to a Camera position matrix, and back?

Tags: c++, opencv, 3d, geometry, opencv3.0

I want to project a 3D scene with a moving camera (animated over time). I have a 3x3 transformation matrix, calculated by `A2 * (T * (R * A1))` where

`A1` is 2D -> 3D matrix projection (I'm currently projecting a single 2D image but will extend to 3D points and remove this matrix)

`T` is Translation matrix

`R` is rotation matrix

`A2` is 3D -> 2D matrix

I can use this in opencv's `warpPerspective` and get a decent result. Now, I want to move the camera position in 3D space, but have no idea how. OpenCV has a `DecomposeProjectionMatrix` which takes a 3x4 projection matrix, but I'm unclear how that relates to any that I have.

Comment: This is about opengl, but the basic principles are the same. http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/

Comment: @Rook excellent resource---bookmarked for the future!

Comment: see [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)